# coding reduceByKey(lambda) in map does'nt work pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, lambda, jupyter-notebook

I can't understand why my code isn't working. The last line is the problem:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark import SQLContext
conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("mein soft")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

lines=sc.textFile("File.txt")
#lines.repartition(3)
lines.getNumPartitions()

def lan_map(x):
    if "word1" and "word2" in x:
        return ("Count",(1,1))
    elif "word1" in x:
        return ("Count",("1,0"))
    elif "word2" in x:
        return ("Count",("0,1"))
    else:
        return ("Count",("0,0"))
    
mapfun=lines.map(lan_map)

mapfun.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1])).collect()
```

And the error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 #Esto resume lo que se hicimos 3 celdas atrás.
> ----> 2 mapfun.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1])).collect()
> 3
> 4 #mapfun.reduceByKey(noMeFuncaLambdaAsiQueHagoEsto(mapfun.x,mupfun.y)).collect()
> 5 #Esto nos devuelve directamente el recuento de cuántas veces aparece "Python" y cuántas aparece "Spark"
>
> C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
> 947         """
> 948         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
> --> 949             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
> 950         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
> 951
>
> C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py
> in **call**(self, *args)    1302     1303         answer =
> self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
> -> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(    1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1306
>
> C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a,
> **kw)
> 109     def deco(*a, **kw):
> 110         try:
> --> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
> 112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
> 113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
>
> C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py
> in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
> 325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> --> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
> 327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
> in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (LAPTOP-PB7QDPVE executor driver):
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
> line 604, in main   File
> "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
> line 594, in process   File
> "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2916, in
> pipeline_func
> return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2916, in
> pipeline_func
> return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 418, in
> func
> return f(iterator)   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2144, in
> combineLocally
> merger.mergeValues(iterator)   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py",
> line 242, in mergeValues
> d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\util.py", line 73, in
> wrapper
> return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "", line 2, in  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +:
> 'int' and 'str'
>
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:652)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
> at
> org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at
> scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
> at
> scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)   at
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2261)     at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)   at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)    at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)  at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
> line 604, in main   File
> "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
> line 594, in process   File
> "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2916, in
> pipeline_func
> return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2916, in
> pipeline_func
> return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 418, in
> func
> return f(iterator)   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2144, in
> combineLocally
> merger.mergeValues(iterator)   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py",
> line 242, in mergeValues
> d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)   File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\util.py", line 73, in
> wrapper
> return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "", line 2, in  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +:
> 'int' and 'str'
>
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:652)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
> at
> org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at
> scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
> at
> scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)   at
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> ... 1 more

I feel so lost that I even can't return just one possition from my funmap. I mean doesnt this should work:

```
mapfun[1]
```

I have tried with a function instead. But I failed worse:

```
def fun2(x,y):
    x[0]+y[0]
    x[1]+y[1]
mapfun.reduceByKey(fun2(x,y)).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

because your tuple values are string i.e. `("1,0")` instead of `(1,0)`, python currently will not apply this operator `+` or add the `int` and `str`(string) data types.

Moreover, there seems to be a logic error in your comparison in your map function where you have `"word1" and "word2" in x` as this will only check if `"word2"` is in `x`. I would recommend the following rewrite:

```py
def lan_map(x):
    if "word1" in x and "word2" in x:
        return ("Count",(1,1))
    elif "word1" in x:
        return ("Count",(1,0))
    elif "word2" in x:
        return ("Count",(0,1))
    else:
        return ("Count",(0,0))
```

or possibly shorter

```py
def lan_map(x):
     return ("Count", (
         1 if "word1" in x else 0,
         1 if "word2" in x else 0
     ))
```

Let me know if this works for you.